# Activate href by javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to click on the first href element by javascript. But I have no idea how to  reach website.com webpage with DOM. Can you tell me pls?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <td><a href="https://website.com" tabindex="-1">hello</a></td>
    <td><a href="">hi</a></td>

    <script src=""></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't get it, do you want to click the `a` tag on the `https://website.com` or on your page?

Comment: `document.querySelector('a').click();` ?  It's not really clear what the problem is or what you mean by "reach website.com webpage with DOM"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<td><a id="yourid" href="https://website.com" tabindex="-1">hello</a></td>
<td><a href="">hi</a></td>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("yourid").click();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

give the first href an id and then paste this code in your script tag: